# PDO Echoing Duplicate Results

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I need to echo a download button if there are certain correct results, but when I echo the download button it decides to echo more than 1. How do I correct this?
heres my code:

```
<?php
    $u = $_SESSION["username"];

    $getscripts = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM project_sa");
    $getscripts->execute();
    while ($row = $getscripts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {

        $sec = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM us WHERE username="wafflezzz"');
        $sec->execute();

        while ($rowx = $sec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
            $checker = $rowx[$row["script_title"]];
            if ($checker == $row["script_title"]) {

                $geturl = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM project_sa WHERE script_title='$checker'");
                $geturl->execute();
                while ($row = $geturl->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {

                    echo '
                      <form method="post" action="dl.php">
                          <input name="bname" value="<?php echo $branded_m_img_url; ?>" hidden></input>
                          <input type="submit" class="ui huge button" value="Download"></input>
                      </form>';
                }

            }

        }

    }

?>
```

It returns about 2 broken duplicate entries when there is only 1 entry in the database!

Comment: You have nested while loops, that's why you get duplicate entries, you also overwrite `$row` in the inner `while` loop

Comment: **WARNING:** Don't leave things like `$checker` in your query string, that's a [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). Instead use the [PDO prepared statements feature](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and represent that as a placeholder. You can pass in the values to `execute()`. Same number of lines of code, yet way, way safer.

Comment: your `echo` HTML is inside a `foreach` loop. Thats why you are getting more than one. Was that what you were asking?

Comment: are you storing table column names inside another table's column in your database?

Comment: I would say the best way for us to help you is for you to show the content of your database tables. It seems like your queries are messed up.

Comment: Alon Eitan told me what I messed up on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You have nested while loops, that's why you get duplicate entries, you also overwrite $row in the inner while loop – Alon Eitan yesterday"

After I fixed that, it worked!